# Why does Elm use the '++' operator to concatenate strings?

Tags: types, syntax, string-concatenation, elm

I am learning Elm and I find a lot of things that are attractive about it, such as its elegance and simplicity.  However, one aspect that I find puzzling is its use of "++" to concatenate strings. For example:

```
> "hello" ++ " world"
"hello world"
```

Addition works the way you would expect it.

```
> 2 + 3 + 9
14
```

The majority of high level languages such as C#/Java/JavaScript/Python  use a single plus "+" in concatenating strings in the analogous way multiple numbers would be summed. It seems so much more intuitive, as there is a certain consistency in concatenating strings like summing numbers.

Does anyone know the logic behind the design decision to use a ++ instead of + in this context?

Comment: Addition is commutative. Appending is not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Elm allows you to define polymorphic functions.

Parametric polymorphism is when a function can be applied to elements of any types:

```
f : (a, b) -> (b, a)
f (x, y) = (y, x)
```

Ad-hoc polymorphism is when a function can be applied to elements of some types:

```
g : appendable -> appendable -> appendable -> appendable
g x y z = x ++ y ++ z

h : number -> number -> number
h x y = (x + 2) * y
```

The type variables `number` and `appendable` are special because they represent a subset of all Elm types. `List` and `String` are `appendable` types while `Float` and `Int` are number types.

It could theoretically be possible to instead define a `hasPlus` type variable which would include `List`, `String`, `Float` and `Int`, but then when defining a polymorphic function you would need to be aware that it is possible that `x + y` is different than `y + x` and that would be quite a burden if you are actually thinking about numbers...

Answer (score 10):

Concatenation and addition are completely different operations with different properties. For example, addition is commutative (on integers, floats are different beasts), while concatenation most definitely is not. The arbitrary decision to re-use the operators by some languages is the strongest connection between them you can find.

And even if the overloading made sense, you would hit the static nature of the language – what should the type of such operator be?

Currently the operator works on magic type `number`:

```
(+) : number -> number -> number
```

While you could have a new magic type `numberorstring` and the `+` function would be polymorphic with two different semantics, this would only be introducing even more magic into the language.

Comment: Your correct, I was not precise in the last part of my question; i.e. I switched my language from concatenation to summation.  I fixed that error. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You are slightly wrong, there is a connection. (String, ++) and (List, ++) are monoids, while e.g. (Int, +) is a abelian group. But any group is also a monoid. But the connection is too weak IMO to be useful in the case of Elm.

Comment: I guess this is part of the reason though [it is in principle possible to define non-commutative addition on generalised rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-semiring) (not to speak of limited-precision floating point numbers, which you’ve already mentioned). In the same vein I’m sure there’s some mathematical formalism that would allow us to consistently define concatenation as a kind of addition.

Comment: @Zimmi48 of course, you are right. I know the algebra but did not want dig too deep into details. I edited the text to make it more precise.

Answer (score 6):

This may be to avoid overloading an operator.

It can be useful to statically infer types or even improve readability when variables are used, as it is then clear what is being done (string concatenation if `++` or arithmetics if `+`).

In languages that are not strongly typed (I do not know if this is the case in Elm), using the same notation can make it impossible to know what is being done on variables before actually running the program, which makes it slower.

XQuery uses `||` instead of `+` too, some languages even use different notations for decimals, like `+.` in CAML.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It definitely sounds plausible.  I was looking for a definitive answer online from either Evan Czaplicki or someone privy to the inner workings of ELM and wasn't able to find one. Hence my question.

Comment: Some other mainstream languages that do not overload `+` for concatenation are PHP (using `.`) and ANSI SQL (using `||`).

Comment: @DaveS If what you want is an answer from an insider, you should ask on the dev mailing list.

Comment: @Zimmi48 - I didn't realize my question was so obscure. In any event. I'm glad I asked it here as I am getting a lot of new insights on the language by the well thought out answers.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [docs](http://elm-lang.org/docs/syntax#applying-functions), the `++` operator is used for appending lists:

```
-- alias for appending lists and two lists
append xs ys = xs ++ ys
xs = [1,2,3]
ys = [4,5,6]

-- All of the following expressions are equivalent:
a1 = append xs ys
a2 = xs ++ ys

b2 = (++) xs ys

c1 = (append xs) ys
c2 = ((++) xs) ys
```

Prior to version 0.9, strings were represented as a Haskell-inspired list of characters. Version 0.9 introduced a new string library (see the [announcement](http://elm-lang.org/blog/announce/0.10#strings) here), so it looks like the `++` operator persisted despite strings no longer being represented as a list.

Comment: From the Elm Core Language Document - "Elm uses the (++) operator to put strings together. Notice that both strings are preserved exactly as is when they are put together so when we combine "hello" and "world" the result has no spaces."  What you say may very well be. I would like to see a definitive answer.  I so far haven't been able to find one, hence my question.

Comment: Is ++ only limited to appending  Lists and Strings?

Comment: [Apparently so](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Basics#++).

Comment: It seems to me that ++ can be called the 'appending' operator